# Available JVM Memory heap space in MB using Python

Tags: python, linux, jvm, heap-memory

How can I achieve the below results?

1. Calculate available JVM Memory Heap space (in MB) of an application from a Linux system using Python?
2. Increase the JVM Memory Heap space (in MB) of an application from a Linux system using Python?

Note - I went through various links in StackOverflow regarding this. I found some Linux commands for the same. But, I need to know how I can write a Python code to achieve the above said two results.

Comment: You can use the os or subprocess module for executing linux commands via python

Comment: You cannot change heap space once the JVM has been started

Comment: @usuario , thank you for this point! Actually in my current use-case, I have a requirement to check the size of the available JVM memory heap space and if it's lesser than an expected value, then it has to be increased. So considering this, could you kindly suggest me the below 3 things please?

1) RedHat linux command to check the free JVM memory heap space
2) RedHat linux command to increase the free JVM memory heap space
3) How we can write these commands in Python code.

Comment: Hi @usuario, I tried using ps -ef | grep java command and I received 2 values -Xms which means min heap value configured and -Xmx which means max heap value configured. But I am in a bit confusion on which command to use to get the free JVM heap space. Do you have any idea on this?